# Cómo hacer una consulta SQL para obtener artículos e imágenes de la misma tabla en Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

¿Cómo hacer una consulta SQL para obtener artículos e imágenes de estos en la misma tabla en Wordpress? He intentado varias consultas pero nada.

La última en la que trabajo es esta que les comparto y donde hago uso de un SELF JOIN.

```
"SELECT p.post_title AS title, p.comment_count, p.post_date, p.guid AS url_post, i.guid AS url_image
FROM wp_post p
LEFT JOIN wp_post i ON p.ID = i.post_parent
WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.comment_status = 'open'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es parte de la estructura de la tabla `wp_posts`. Quiero recuperar las imágenes de mis artículos apoyándome en la columna `post_parent` de la imagen, cuyo valor es el ID de mi artículo, como pueden ver en mi tabla.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Lo fundamental es cómo presentar esa información. Ya que cada línea de resultado a su vez requiere presentar muchas líneas de resultado.
Se me ocurre que tengas una columna donde separados por coma tenga todos los resultados buscados. Es decir, en cada artículo tendría una columna más con todas las imágenes separadas por comas. Después tendrás que procesar esa información.

Eso lo podrías obtener con una **subconsulta** y un **GROUP_CONCAT**. Podría quedar algo así:

```
select table_all_guid.allGuid, p.*
from wp_posts p,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pg.guid) allGuid, pg.id FROM wp_posts pg group by pg.post_parent) table_all_guid
where p.id= table_all_guid.id
```

De modo que en la primera columna tendrías todas las imágenes y en el resto de columnas tendrías todos los demás campos.